# How to pull value from a map

Tags: groovy

I've got a map with bunch of values

```
def mymap = [
"FOO" : "BAR",
"something" : "else"
]
```

I want to pull the value out based on whether a key starts with what I'm passing. i.e.

```
mymap.findAll(it.key.startsWith("FO")}
```

The above returns `{FOO=BAR}`

How can I modify it so that I only get the value `BAR` back?

I tried this but I don't want to `each` because I know it'll always have just one value

```
def val = ""
mymap.findAll(it.key.startsWith("FO")}.each{val = it.value}
assert val == "BAR"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
mymap.findAll { it.key.startsWith("FO") }.values()
```

It will return all values found...

Or if you only query one

```
mymap.find { it.key.startsWith("FO") }.value
```

Answer (score 2):

As you said there will be only one entry, in that case `findResult` will be your best bet

```
mymap.findResult{k, v -> if(k.startsWith('FO')) return v}
```

Moreover, if you want to make it null-safe, you can set a default value as

```
mymap.findResult('default'){k, v -> if(k.startsWith('FO')) return v}
```

In case you want to collect all such values as a list you would need `collectMany`:

```
mymap.collectMany{k, v -> k.startsWith('FO') ? [v] : []}
```

**Sample:**

```
def mymap = ["FOO": "BAR", "something": "else", "FOOD": "Bread", "FOOL": "John Doe"]

assert mymap.findResult{k, v -> if(k.startsWith('FO')) return v} == 'BAR'
assert mymap.collectMany{k, v -> k.startsWith('FO') ? [v] : []} == ['BAR', 'Bread', 'John Doe']
assert mymap.findResult('default'){k, v -> if(k.startsWith('BLAH')) return v} == 'default'
```